# Add items to the end of a queue

Tags: java, queue

How can I take the head of a queue and add items to the end?

I have made a method called add which is

```
add(Node<E> head, E item) {

}
```

---

```
class Node<E> {
    E item;
    Node<E> next;

    Node(E item, Node<E> next) {
        this.item = item;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

Comment: E item;
   Node<E> next;

   Node(E item, Node<E> next)
   {
      this.item = item;
      this.next = next;
   }
}

Comment: I rolled back your edit: it is better if your question provides sample code of what you tried.

Comment: thanks. It seems to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last node is the node which has no next element, i.e. the node where `next == null`.

Given a node `head`, it is then possible to loop over all the next elements, until we reach the one where `next == null`. To add an element at the end is therefore to set the `next` variable of the current last element to the element added and setting its `next` variable to `null` (to indicate that it's the new last element).

```
private static <E> void add(Node<E> head, E item) {
    Node<E> last = head;
    while (last.next != null) {
        last = last.next;
    }
    last.next = new Node<>(item, null);
}
```

Test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Node<String> node = new Node<>("1", new Node<>("2", null));
    System.out.println(node); // prints 1 -> 2
    add(node, "3");
    System.out.println(node); // prints 1 -> 2 -> 3
}
```

with the following `toString()` addition to `Node`:

```
class Node<E> {
    E item;
    Node<E> next;

    Node(E item, Node<E> next) {
        this.item = item;
        this.next = next;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return item + (next == null ? "" : " -> " + next);
    }

}
```

Comment: To fix: Infinite loop in case of adding new node to a node ring ;)

Comment: @boly38 I hadn't thought of that, you're correct (left as an exercise for the reader :) )

Answer (score 0):

Since a node has a reference to its next node, you need to traverse through it until you reach the end.

If the end is null, you could use a while loop:

```
void add(Node<E> head, E item)
{
    // head.next == null means we reached the end
    while (head.next != null)
    {
        /*
         * Note that the "real" head is not changed by that, we just assign
         * a new value to head
         */
        head = head.next;
    }

    /*
     * the parameter head is now set to the last node, so we can set the
     * item
     */
    head.item = item;
    // or if you want to add an new node
    head.next = new Node<>(item, null);
}
```